# Get a list of all logged in Keycloak users in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

Right now I am able to get a list of all keycloak users in javascript, but it is a list of all users regardless of online status. Is there any way to get a list of users that are online (or logged in)?

I am trying to create a drop down list with only the online users. I have the list show in the browser, but it is all the user accounts. There could be potentially thousands of user accounts and that wouldn't be useful to scroll through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for active login sessions. This could be archieved via Keycloak admin rest API. You could use and Keycloak Admin Console as a reference implementation of Admin API client. Use developer mode in your browser to trace which endpoint should be requested.